# Firefox not recognizing <br />

Tags: html, firefox

For the life of me, I cannot figure out why the code at [www.moosecodes.com](http://www.moosecodes.com) works on Safari and Chrome but when I open it with Firefox the browser doesn't recognize any of the line breaks!

i.e. `<br/>`

I have a suspicion that it is because I haven't declared a doctype, but its just a regular old run line break that isn't being interpreted. Anyone know the answer?

EDIT: To see what I mean, go to the site and click on "resume" then click on "Experience" or "Research"

[image: picture of broken text]
<sub>(source: [moosecodes.com](http://moosecodes.com/jumbledtext.png))</sub>

Comment: Which page? Don't make us search for them.

Comment: Its all one page, im using scripts to display everything on one page since the site doesnt have a ton of info.. plus i think it looks kinda cool... you will only have to make two clicks to see what i the jumbled text. once you get to the site you will know what i mean.

Comment: I don't see it. How about a screenshot.

Comment: Too many W3 errors to debug. Try fixing the errors first.

Comment: Side note: You shouldn't have multiple elements with the same ID.  Instead of doing `id="myHeadings"` multiple times, do `class="myHeadings"`.

Comment: All elements are set to `position: absolute`, and you have at least two elements there which reasonably overlap. Opera apparently displays it as you intend it, but I would assume Firefox is correct (or they both are). Also, that is horrible site navigation.

Comment: @Anonymous, can you suggest some improvements for the site navigation? i would be open to any ideas. Also, its worth noting that the site isn't done yet.

Comment: Mooseman: above all, allow each section to be bookmarked. Using fragment identifiers in conjunction with your current script would result in the exact same interface plus bookmarkable sections. (And personally, I hate slow animations like that, but that's not as much of an annoyance as somebody describing a path of clicks rather than providing a direct URL.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have everything on your page set to `position: absolute` with the following CSS.

```
* {
    color: #C8C8EB;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
}
```

That's a very bad universal style to have, only apply `position: absolute` to what you need it applied to and it'll fix your `<br />` problem (and probably others too!). or you could target the `<br />` directly to set it back to default.

```
br {
    position: static;
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct with your analysis, but setting the position for the br alone won't fix it, as his myHeadings div is also positioned absolute. I have no clue why you would ever apply position absolute on ALL elements. :)

Comment: Being as this is your portfolio, I'd use the W3C validation tool to make sure you've got no glaring errors. http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.moosecodes.com%2F